# Problems to display average rating with Solspace Rating

Tags: solspace-rating

I need some help, about Solspace Rating,

If the entry named **hamburger** was rated 20 times,  there are 20 **Entry's Rating** with the **hamburger** name, in the Rating's Control Panel.

When I Using this code, the 20 **Entry's Rating** of the Hamburger **Rated entries** are displayed on 20 lines. How to display only one line, and not all the entries, where appear the average note of all the hamburger **Entry's Rating** and of the other ones?

```
{exp:rating:entries}
        <ul>
            <li>
                {exp:rating:stats entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                     {stars_avg_rating}
                {/exp:rating:stats}
            </li>
        </ul>
{/exp:rating:entries}
```

**Update:**

Using this code, appear the average's notes of the **Rated entries**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="receitas"}
    {exp:rating:entries limit="1" }
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {exp:rating:stats entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                         {title}{stars_avg_rating}
                    {/exp:rating:stats}
                </li>
            </ul>
    {/exp:rating:entries}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Does exist a more direct method than parsing **exp:rating:entries** inside **exp:channel:entries** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:-

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="receitas"}
        <li>
            {exp:rating:stats entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                {title} - {stars_overall_avg}
            {/exp:rating:stats}
        </li>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Comment: Andrew, the problem was independent about the <ul> position  , all the Rating entries was displaying. I found a better solution than exp:channel in this case: using {exp:rating:rank} instead {exp:rating:entries}, no need more exp:channel:entries.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Could you submit it as an answer here so others can clearly see in future?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

the problem was independent about the `<ul>` position , all the Rating's entries was displaying. I found a better solution than to parse inside **exp:channel** in this case: using **{exp:rating:rank}** instead **{exp:rating:entries}**, no need more exp:channel:entries.

```
<ul>
{exp:rating:rank}
        {exp:rating:stats entry_id="{entry_id}"}
               <li>
                    {exp:rating:stats entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                         {title}{stars_avg_rating}
                    {/exp:rating:stats}
                </li>
                {/exp:rating:stats}
{/exp:rating:rank}
</ul>
```